# mod_pagespeed rewrite just path, using the same domain

Tags: mod-pagespeed

I'm trying to configure mod_page speed to rewrite/change the path of resources it modifies.

For example to put example.com/test.css (once it is modified by mod page speed) at example.com/modps/test.css

I have tried using the MapRewriteDomain, which works if doing domainA/path to domainB/newpath

However this seems to be ignored if the domains are the same, even though the path is different.

For example:

This works - pagespeed MapRewriteDomain

```
http://example1.com/test/ http://example.com;
```

This doesn't work - pagespeed MapRewriteDomain

```
http://example.com/test/ http://example.com;
```

The format is pagespeed MapRewriteDomain domain_to_write_into_html                           domain_specified_in_html;

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I'd like to put all rewritten resources on a unique path for traffic routing purposes.

Comment: Why are you trying to put rewritten resources on a unique path?

Comment: @JeffKaufman it was for traffic management purposes

Comment: Can you just manage traffic based on all rewritten resources having the substring ".pagespeed."?